# Python MYSQL - insert distinct values

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, insert, distinct-values

I have a database table with a simple id and name columns, and a csv file with some dummy names where some of them are duplicates. I'm trying to read only the unique values.

```
def readCsv(fileName):
#open connection
reader = csv.DictReader(open(fileName, encoding="utf8"))
connection = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER=' + DRIVER + ';PORT=1433;SERVER=' + SERVER + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + DATABASE + ';UID=' + USERNAME + ';PWD=' + PASSWORD)
cursor = connection.cursor()

#Reading of the file
counter = 0
#Iterate line by line
for line in reader:
    insertSql = "INSERT INTO Dummy VALUES(?)"
    result = cursor.execute(insertSql,
                            line['name'])
    cursor.commit()
    counter+= 1
```

This correctly inputs all the names in the database, but I have duplicate names that I don't want. 
I've tried using INSERT IGNORE, but that somehow returns an error that INTO isn't correct?

```
insertSql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO Dummy VALUES(?)"
```

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I've had a similar result with using  ON DUPLICATE, where it just says now ON isn't valid.

```
insertSql = "INSERT INTO Dummy VALUES(?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=name"
```

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Ive thought that one of those should work, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here?